# Найти слово и удалить с несколькими условиями

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти слова с несколькими параметрами (1 - `"_word"`, 2 -`"(Qs123Da)"`, 3 - `"Кирилица"`) и удалить их. С условием что слово перед `"Кирилица"` тоже будет удалена, т.е. `"f914 Кирилица"`.
Может быть что одна или несколько искомых словом может и не присутствовать в исходном тексте.

Пример:

```
String s = "Word word T123 f914 Кирилица (Qs123Da)_word"
String ss = "Word word HN654 (Am123s)_word"
```

В результате должно получиться

```
s = "Word word T123"
ss = "Word word HN654"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно вызвать метод [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)):

1. `str = str.replaceAll("_word", "")`
2. `str = str.replaceAll("\\(Qs123Da\\)", "")`
3. `str = str.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z0-9]+ Кирилица", "")`

UPD:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String s = "Word word T123 f914 Кирилица (Qs123Da)_word";

      s = s.replaceAll("([a-zA-Z0-9]+ Кирилица)? \\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)_word", "");

      System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно это все выполнить в один раз? 2-е условие, в скобках всегда разные значения. Пробовал так `"\\(^[()]*\\)"` но почему-то не удаляет

Comment: @dev.android, нет, не думаю. Если Вы объедините все в одно регулярное выражение, как у Вас это сработает для второго примера (слово "Кириллица" отсутствует) ? На счет разных значений: замените содержимое скобок на [a-zA-Z0-9]+.

Comment: @dev.android, хотя, подождите минуту.

Comment: @dev.android, обновил.

Comment: Спасибо большое, все работает

Comment: @dev.android, рад помочь!